# Migrar mi Vue js 2 usando CDN a TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

No sé si estoy en lo correcto, pero estoy intentando mejorar mi JS usando TypeScript
Actualmente, tengo mi archivo HTML y estoy importando Vue js por CDN para ocuparlo directamente en mi div con id="app"

Mi archivo JS luce asi:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
  cliente: {
    nombre: "",
    edad: 0,
  },
  proyectos: [],
  proyecto: {},
},
methods: {
  verCliente: function () {
    var proyectosDemo = [
      {
        nombre: "Proyecto 1",
        cliente: {
          nombre: "Cliente 1",
          edad: 30,
          trabajo: "demo"
        },
        fecha: "2022-01-01",
        estado: "En progreso",
      },
      {
         nombre: "Proyecto 2",
         cliente: {
           nombre: "Cliente 2",
           edad: 25,
         },
         fecha: "2022-02-01",
         estado: "Terminado",
       },
     ];
     for (var i = 0; i < proyectosDemo.length; i++) {
       this.proyectos.push(proyectosDemo[i]);
     }
     this.cliente.proyectos = this.proyectos;
     return this.cliente;
    },
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.verCliente();
  },
});
```

Y estoy empezando en el mundo de TS actualmente mi código luce así:

```
declare var Vue: any;

interface Cliente {
  nombre: string;
  edad: number;
  trabajo?: string;
}
interface Proyecto {
  nombre: string;
  cliente: Cliente;
  fecha: string;
  estado: string;
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    cliente: {
      nombre: "",
      edad: 0,
    } as Cliente,
    proyectos: [],
    proyecto: {} as Proyecto,
  },
  methods: {
    verCliente: function (): void {

      const proyectosDemo: Proyecto[] = [
        {
          nombre: "Proyecto 1",
          cliente: {
            nombre: "Cliente 1",
            edad: 30,
            trabajo: "demo"
          },
          fecha: "2022-01-01",
          estado: "En progreso",
        },
        {
          nombre: "Proyecto 2",
          cliente: {
            nombre: "Cliente 2",
            edad: 25,
          },
          fecha: "2022-02-01",
          estado: "Terminado",
        },
      ];
      for (let i = 0; i < proyectosDemo.length; i++) {
        this.proyectos.push(proyectosDemo[i]);
      }

      this.cliente.proyectos = this.proyectos;
      return this.cliente;
    },
  },
  mounted: function (): void {
    this.verCliente();
  },
});
```

Luego de esto compilo con TS usando tsc myFile.ts y el resultado es el archivo JS
Mi pregunta es, ¿estoy usando de la mejor manera TS, vale la pena seguir por este camino?
¿Es mucha perdida de tiempo usar TS?
¿Vale la pena hoy día usar TS?
Soy desarrollador FullStack y actualmente llevo un equipo de 3 desarrolladores que apenas se mueven en js y mi archivo JS es de 15,000 líneas, es un desatre por eso quisiera usar TS para ir dando mucho mas orden.

Comment: hay múltiples razones para cerrar tu pregunta como que... haces más de una pregunta, que algunas de ellas solo se pueden responder con opiniones, etc. Tal vez mejor quieras preguntar como configurar tu vue para que te haga la compilación y exportación de manera automática sin que tengas que correr typescript manualmente (que es lo que entendí en tu redacción que hacías)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

desde mi opinión creo que:

- Typescript es un lenguaje genial para desarrollar, tanto a nivel personal como profesional.
- Si miras estadisticas y los típicos state of.. anuales veras que no para de crecer y que cada vez se pide más profesionalmente y por lo tanto se paga mejor.
- Debido al tipado permite evitar muchisimos errores comunes de javascript y a la vez tiene cierta flexibilidad, puedes meter any's por todos lados y librarte de hacer las cosas bien (no es malo) puede servir para alguien que este empezando o no tenga aun la soltura y así no atasca y puede producir.
- Te muestra errores de la que picas código y te muestra los params de una función etc lo cual me parece muy cómodo.
- También permite que el código sea compatible ya que lo puedes configurar y al traspilar te genera los pollyfill correspondientes.

Resumen le veo muchas cosas buenas y pocas malas. Pero al final creo que es una decisión de cada empresa / responsable / equipo.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo tomaré mucho, en cuenta gracias por el apoyo, vamos a seguir desarrollando.